# How can I position a particular Item to "Left Top" corner using UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: scrolltop, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using UICollectionView with Custom Layout. In that whenever collectionview getting reloaded, I need {0,0} item should be positioned to Top Left corner of contentView. If I'm setting scroll position to "UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop" it will scroll {0,0} item to Top only but not to Left Top corner.

So, How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using contentOffset I had done this easily.

i.e. Every time before I reload UICollectionView I had been set the collectionView's contentOffset to CGPointZero without animation. It worked nicely! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using the `UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:` method, then you can (bitwise) combine the scroll position indicators like this:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView = .....;
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                       atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop | UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                               animated:YES];
```

This way you can combine the x- and y-axis scroll position.
Hope this helps!